# Select 3 values from table1 and use one of the values from table1 in table2 to fetch results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Hi Stackoverflow members!

I got this dilemma:

```html
users  ID  username  firstname  middlename lastname
        1  bilbodog    Casper               Thomsen
        2  bilbodog2   Smith      John      Andersen


flirts    flirter_id  flirted_id  date  time
              1          2          X    X
```

I wanna get all the flirted_id's made by the flirter_id '1' and compare the flirted_id to users and gather the firstname, middlename & lastname from the flirted_id. Plus I wanna gather the date and time from the flirts table. Then I wanna echo the results out in a HTML table.

So for now I am doing this:

```html
<?php
$ID=$_SESSION['ID'];
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT flirted_id, date, time FROM flirts WHERE flirter_id='$ID'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  ----> ECHO TABLE <----
} else {
  echo 'No flirts found.';
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

But that does not work.

I am so stuck at this point. I dunno how to gather 3 results from 1 table and use one of the results to compare at table 2, to gather the firstname, middlename and lastname of the person that goes by that ID.

- Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to do a join to grab the information from table1  and also the information about the person in table 2 who is listed as `added_id` in table1

```
select t1.date, t1.time, t2.first, t2.middle, t2.last
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on (t1.added_id = t2.id)
where t1.adder_id = 1;
```

If you also want the information about the `adder_id` (assuming the persons are also stored in table2):

```
select t1.date, t1.time, t2.first, t2.middle. t2.last, t3.first, t3.middle, t3.last
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on (t1.added_id = t2.id)
join table2 t3 on (t1.added_id = t3.id)
where t1.adder_id = 1;
```

In this case you should give the person cols alias to identify them more cleary, e.g. `t2.first as added_id_first, t3.first as adder_id_first` and so on

**Note** I assume that there are no NULL values in the `adder_id` and `added_id` fields. If they can then use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` in the statements.

Comment: I dont want any information about the adder_id, but thanks anyways!
So how am I supposed to echo the results, then?
Just like this:
echo $row["first"], $row["middle"], $row["last"];
or like this:
echo $row["t2.first"], $row["t2.middle"], $row["last"];
?

Comment: So you want to use the first query of my answer: Then you can just use `echo $row['first']` as the col-names and so the array keys are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
select concat (table2.first," ",table2.middle ) as adder_id_Name,AddedName.* from table2,(SELECT concat (tb2.first," ",tb2.middle ) as added_id_Name,  tb1.adder_id from table2 tb2,table1 tb1 where tb1.added_id = tb2.ID) as AddedName where table2.ID = AddedName.adder_id
```

Comment: And that I did not understand anything of! :O
I am not like a proffesional to all this MySQL yet. I am trying to learn it.

Comment: First   ---> SELECT concat (tb2.first," ",tb2.middle ) as added_id_Name,  tb1.adder_id from table2 tb2,table1 tb1 where tb1.added_id = tb2.ID

Comment: From this sql you get added_id's name

Comment: @bilbodog `concat()` is putting strings together to one string. So the combines the first and middle name to one string and also puts a space between them. After that names this new, imaginary col as `added_id_Name`.

Comment: Like I thought, those total un-understandable advanced explanings. I just got an error on my page..
"syntax error, unexpected '",tb2.middlename ) as added_id' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)"

Comment: i think you try another sql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83701/discussion-between-bilbodog-and-anand-somasekhar).

Comment: rectify your problem ??

Comment: My problem is still the exact same, just that I have made some other names instead of the ones I really got, because we can't post them online, but doesn't matter. We will just change them after we understand how this is done. So please explain it again just with those informations, then I can maybe understand it better than before. It would be perfect.

Comment: In my sql first work inner sql / inside "()" part  [ SELECT concat (tb2.first," ",tb2.middle ) as added_id_Name,  tb1.adder_id from table2 tb2,table1 tb1 where tb1.added_id = tb2.ID] .  Here i just take first name and middle name , if needed you take last name.

Answer (score 0):

I found out by myself. I strangled my brain and got this as the answer:

```
                              <?php
                                    // Create connection
                                    $conn = new mysqli($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
                                    // Check connection
                                    if ($conn->connect_error) {
                                        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                                    }
                                        $sql = "SELECT from_id, message, date, time FROM messages WHERE to_id='$ID'";
                                        $result = $conn->query($sql);
                                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                        // output data of each row
                                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                            $from_id=$row["from_id"];
                                            $message=$row["message"];
                                            $date=$row["date"];
                                            $time=$row["time"];
                                            $sql10 = "SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname FROM users WHERE ID='$from_id'"; 
                                            $sql11 = mysql_query($sql10); 
                                            $sql12 = mysql_fetch_row($sql11);
                                            $firstname=$sql12[0];
                                            $middlename=$sql12[1];
                                            $lastname=$sql12[2];
                                            ?>
                                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                                <span class="label label-default"><?php echo $date, ' ', $time; ?></span>
                                                <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                                <span class="name" style="min-width: 120px; display: inline-block;">Casper Thomsen</span>
                                                <span class="text-muted" style="font-size: 11px;">- <?php echo $message; ?></span>
                                                <span class="pull-right">
                                                    <button type="submit" id="view_message" name="view_message" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right">L&aelig;s  Besked <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
                                                </span>
                                            </a>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        echo '
                                        <div class="block block-team_member_block span12 first cf">
                                            <div class="member">
                                                <div class="member-social">
                                                </div>
                                                <h3>No members or could not connect to database..</h3>
                                                <div class="bline"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>';
                                    }
                                    $conn->close();
                                ?>
```